# Is it possible to configure global timeout for all request in spring cloud gateway

Tags: spring, timeout, hystrix, spring-cloud-gateway

I am trying to add global timeout for all rquests in my api gateway. Below is my routing bean:

```
@Configuration
public class DataserviceRoute {

    @Bean
    public RouteLocator customRouteLocator(RouteLocatorBuilder builder) {
        return builder.routes()
                .route("abc_service",
                        r -> r.path("/abc/**").uri("http://localhost:7010"))
                .route("def_service",
                        r -> r.path("/def/**").uri("http://localhost:8085"))
                .route("xyz_service",
                        r -> r.path("/xyz/**").uri("http://localhost:1800"))
                .build();
    }
}
```

How do I configure global timeouts for all routes?

Answer (score 0):

I found my answer. I configured the bean as below:

```
@Bean
    public RouteLocator customRouteLocator(RouteLocatorBuilder builder) {
        return builder.routes()
                .route(r -> r.path("/**")
                        .filters(f -> f.hystrix(config -> config.setName("appTimeout")))
                        .uri("http://localhost:8085")
                        .id("all_request"))
                .build();
    }
```

and added a property in `application.property` file:

```
hystrix.command.appTimeout.execution.isolation.thread.timeoutInMilliseconds: 30000
```

Comment: However, the timeout response I get from gateway has empty body. I am not able to add custom message in response for the timeout. any help in this will be appreciated.